# How to resolve the issue of google play console not letting me to upload new version of signed apk because of permission related issue

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to rollout a new version of my app to playstore. However I receive an error message saying **"Check these errors before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the errors on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app."** I am sure that my app does not include call or sms permission. Has anyone faced similar type of issue? See below screenshot for more details

> ERROR IMAGE

[image]

> ERROR IMAGE

[image]

Comment: What are the actual errors?

Comment: use android studio manifest merger to check if any library adds any suspicious permission

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Comment: It says to fillout permission declaration form while trying to do full rollout. However permission that has been added in my app are:-

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

Comment: Does anyone know how to view the permission declaration form ?

Comment: I already asked this issue but no solution now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361014/google-play-console-said-you-cant-edit-this-app-until-you-create-a-new-app-rel/54361134?noredirect=1#comment95537416_54361134

Comment: @sudeeppandey any solution. share here

Comment: @Rameshbabu It was automatically solved with new release apk .

Comment: @deaddroid it should pop up when you're trying to release a version with sensitive permissions used in your app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google play console said "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions" how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361014/google-play-console-said-you-cant-edit-this-app-until-you-create-a-new-app-rel)

Comment: Check my answer, I had the same problem and I solved it by accident https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371314/i%C2%B4m-getting-the-following-error-from-play-console-and-i-can%C2%B4t-edit-the-version-o/54390732#54390732