# Google play console said "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions" how to fix it?

Tags: android, release, google-play-console

I couldn't publish my new released on `google play console` this morning. It has shown,

> "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions"

And it does not provide the option to fix. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: same issue - while uploading a build today any luck ?

Comment: @AbubakarRafi i found this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102#  but no option to complete form

Comment: Hi @stayfighter any solutions you got. Please share if any.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373255/google-play-console-preventing-uploading-or-promoting-new-app-versions-compliant/54406150

Comment: Ckech my answer, I had the same problem and I solved it by accident https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371314/i%C2%B4m-getting-the-following-error-from-play-console-and-i-can%C2%B4t-edit-the-version-o/54390732#54390732

Answer (score 11):

In my case Google removed my app from production, to be able to submit a new release without using the sms i had to:

- Retain the previous release (where i was using sms),
- Because of the first step the permission form appeared,
- I filled the form
- Added the new apk (without sms)
- Deactivated the old apk
- Only then i was able to roll to production.

This is not the intended behavior based on the email i received from google when my app was removed:

> Option 1) If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions:
>
> Remove the specified permissions from your app’s manifest, or migrate to an alternative implementation, then publish the updated version of your app using the standard release process.

So adding the apk that do not have sms in it should work but it did not until i retained the old one, filled the form, and deactivated the old apk.

Comment: "Retain the previous release" is what allowed me to finally see and alter the permissions.  Took over an hour to figure that out!!!

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do and now it at least shows that it's in full rollout so keeping my fingers crossed...although I also see the "App removed" message all over android console.  Google should really get it together.

Answer (score 8):

I meet the same problem today. In my case, my app still has an alpha release which declared sensitive permissions, so I manage alpha release, and click RELEASE TO PRODUCTION button.In the PREPARE RELEASE page, "Declare sensitive permissions" session appears.

After finish the form and save the release, I just discard it and manager the PRODUCTION TRACK again.

hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Somehow it worked for me even without form. By putting it directly to production. Even though I didn't want to!

Answer (score 3):

> This is the list of sensitive permissions that google wants us to
>   include in app before publishing it.
>
> Also, We got an extension until March 9 2019 from Google about the SMS permissions.

```
android.permission.INTERNET

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

android.permission.BLUETOOTH

android.permission.CAMERA

android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

android.permission.SEND_SMS

android.permission.READ_SMS

android.permission.VIBRATE

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS

android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS

android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS

android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS

android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS

android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT

android.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT

android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

com.android.vending.BILLING
```

Comment: Hi @Devraj i have removed the SMS related all the permissions. What about the above mentioned details. where has to include.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take run time permission from user as you have some sensitive permission in the app like read or write external storage or something else.
So take run time permission from user and rebuild the app and release.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions tell you what to do if you can't see the form: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102

You could also have more complicated issues if you have testing and production track whose APKs/Bundles require different permissions. You need all the permissions from the different release tracks to be in a single release (in one release track).

Answer (score 0):

**Google’s restrictions on SMS/Call Log permissions policy**

You need to implement the :

> SMS Retriver API

in order to remove those permission and leave them only in the needed time. Follow as stated here : [Sms Retriver API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) . If you need more help let me know, i have implemented it already.

Comment: I have removed the sms and call related permissions. Google play store still rejecting the app. I have no idea where am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing issue same kinda issue. It was from Google side in my case. 
**Solution**:
If you have `production` apk(even with no sms permission used) with v225 &
 `Internal test track` with **v900**(even with no sms permission used) , then

> You should  submit higher version

i.e. **v900+** apk(with no sms permission used ofcourse) to `production`, this error will be dissappeared and you'll be able to rollout.

Google should have ignored `Internal test track` apk in first place but nevertheless this thing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced same issue. After a long research i have fixed this.

First make sure you have removed the permission which is mention by Google' Polices.

> First need to **Deactivate Old App**.

Follow the below instruction. Please make sure you do this process in Beta track:

1. Create a release
2. Don't select or drop the new APK now.
3. Give any name which is your old app name into the Release Name section.
4. Save the changes(Hope it not ask any error).
5. Press Review and then Start Rollout to production.(Don't worry it will only deactivate the Old App.)

Now can't see your old apk in beta section.
Then you can do your as usual beta release.It will not ask the Declaration Form.

hope this will help for your headache.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer. The prompt one went away once I published updates to all channels.

From play support email exchange...

> You'll just need to assure you release a compliant APK to each track
>   that has the sensitive permissions, as this likely happened because
>   the Permissions form in the Play Console saw multiple APKs.
>
> However, please be assured our engineers are looking into streamlining
>   this process, and I apologize for any inconvenience.
>
> Support's instructions are...

To upload a new APK, you need to submit the declaration form for all the permissions that you’re currently using in your app. Please see the following instructions to submit the form:

1. Go to the Console > App release > Click ‘Create a release’ > Upload a new APK that you want to release
2. Retain the current version of APK
3. Click ‘Add from library’ > Upload all active APKs to cover all permissions across the tracks in your app
4. You can find active APK in Release management > Artifact library
5. Fill out the Declaration Form > Click "Save" at the bottom of the page

> After that, please stay on the same page and follow the next steps:

1. Deactivate and remove ONLY the old APKs which you do not want to release.
2. Click "Save" again then select "Review"
3. Then, you'll be able to release a new version of APK by clicking "Start Roll Out" button.

Also, if you do not want to use an APK (with sensitive or high-risk permission) under other track, please do not forget to replace them to a new APK.