# Cannot update APK after removing SMS and Call log permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

My app was removed by Google because it used SMS and call log permissions, namely `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` and `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` which I've removed from the AndroidManifest.xml file

Ater removing these permission from the manifest and related feature, I'm trying to update the app with an updated APK.

But in the google console's , when I hit the "check" button I get the error:

```
To modify this application, first create a new release by declaring the sensitive permissions.
```

Could you please let me know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I've followed this answer provided by @jee and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514935/2068732

Comment: Question relates to a publication issue which is not directly related with programming, and depends on an external company

Answer (score 0):

create your release key and upload on the play store 
then you will see there play store ask about the permission 
if you have SMS and CALL permission

then choose Default handler option and provide the user name and password (if app have login/signup)

after that, you will 4 checkboxes also now select all checkbox

then finally submit your app