# Google Play Console preventing uploading or promoting new app versions compliant with sensitive permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an existing app published to production and beta tracks that require SMS permissions.  In order to comply with Google's recent policy changes on these permissions I have removed all SMS permissions and have new versions with higher version codes that do NOT require these permissions sitting in both internal-test and alpha tracks.

I am unable to either promote these compliant versions to beta or production tracks or upload new higher versions directly to beta or production tracks.  I am always presented with the red "changes cannot be saved" bar.  I am unable to disable or remove testers from beta track as suggested by Google, "Alternatively, consider deactivating any Open, Closed, or Internal testing tracks that are not currently in use if they are not compliant with this policy."  I am also not presented with a "Permissions Declaration Form" anywhere in the console.

The Play Console seems to have me stuck in a loop where I "...can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions." and I can't create a new app release because I can't edit the app.

I just want to publish a new higher version of my app with the SMS permissions removed, not declare them as required.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This sort of situation is best resolved by contacting Google Play Console support, which is on the help menu behind the "?" icon. There may be a bug affecting your position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same exact issue.
It seems there's no way to workaround it without accepting the inline *Permission Declaration Form*.

The way I fixed the issue is by:

1. Click the **Create Release** in a target channel.
2. Upload new APK having higher version with the SMS permissions removed.
3. [IMPORTANT] Click on **RETAIN** on previous (the one that contains the SMS permissions) version - which will present the inline *Permission Declaration Form*.
4. In *Permission Declaration Form*, under `Compliance status` (*Does this release meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy? If you choose no, you can submit the form without selecting any core functionalities.*), select **No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy**.
5. Check all check-boxes under `Declarations` (*By submitting this Permissions Declaration Form, I confirm that*).
6. Click the **Save** and then **Review** buttons.
7. You will be navigated to `Review and rollout screen`, and **Rollout** button will be finally enabled.

In order to remove the retained version (from step 3 - the one that contains the SMS permissions), you can create another release (with an APK having higher version) - in which you'll be able to deactivate any previous versions.

Comment: Thank you!  Your steps worked for me.  I uploaded a new version to beta track, clicking "retain" on the old version finally showed me the inline form, and I was able to roll out the new beta version.  Once the new beta version was up I was able to promote that to production without further issues.

Comment: I can't proceed with step 4. The permission declaration form is never displayed

Comment: @Granjero Perhaps the retained APK doesn't include SMS permissions. Do you have another track where the APK includes SMS permissions?

Comment: WWOOOWWW - I had a `closed alpha track` that had an old version of code in that was causing my issue.  But man, getting rid of it was a pain.  Steps above pretty much worked for me.  Over write your existing Alpha track with a new APK...forcing the old to be deactivated, then promote the new Alpha to Production.  Crap Google...you do any more stuff like that you will start looking a lot like the insane Apple App roll out process.....which is utter hell.

Comment: Did it take everyone longer than usual to have their app re-roll out to the store?  Still waiting for mine to get approved (but the above steps worked)

Comment: But I'm getting error like "Your changes could not be saved. Please try again."

Comment: I answered a similar question with a slightly different approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593333/7354094

Comment: Could not find step 3!!

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ajddj6/play_store_console_you_cant_edit_this_app_until/eexhopn):

> I finally got this to work. I created a new release but didnt upload a new APK, in this release I deactivated all the previous APKs except the current one. In this release form you are presented with a sensitive permissions declaration form on which i declared that the release did not comply with the new regulations. (This prompts a warning that you must comply before march 19). After rolling out this release, which basically changed nothing because no new APK was made available, I created a new release with the new APK that I wanted to publish, this went on normally and is currently in rollout.

Please also try other solutions from this link.

Comment: _"This prompts a warning that you must comply before march 19"_ Sounds to me like he/she didn't actually fix the problem, and just postponed dealing with it until a slightly later date.

Comment: @Michael After that you can actually update your app in production - e.g. remove these features from your app, this will comply new policy.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my process was a bit different:

> 1. Ensure Alpha or Beta track does not have OLD APK with permissions violations.
> 2. If it does, Delete/Deactive the Beta and Alpha ones before uploading a new one to Production.
> 3. If you can't simply `delete` or `deactivate` an Alpha or Beta release, which some are finding to the be the problem (as was my
>      problem), then you must overwrite the existing Alpha/Beta versions
>      with a new version...that forces the Alpha/Beta to auto-deactivate.
> 4. Alpha/Beta `Manage`  -> `Create Release` -> upload a new APK (even if its to be your next Production version)
> 5. Ensure the previous one is showing `Deactivated`, then `Save`, `Review` and `Release`.  I got all kinds of warnings/severe warnings about not having Alpha user lists and not being deployed to thousands of devices.  I ignore those and `released` anyway.
> 6. **I never got a `Restricted Permissions Form` on my newly uploaded APK because I had already removed the need for them in my app.**
> 7. After the old one is gone, then go back into that Alpha/Beta release you just created and `Promote to Production` - SAVE, REVIEW,
>      RELEASE again.

Hope this helps someone out there.  Took me 2 hours of frustration to finally get around this mess.

Google should just allow you to delete Alpha/Beta versions - or more specifically, not even consider them valid Production....or even more so, LABEL which versions are not passing the requirements.  It took me a good hour just to figure out it was a 1.5 year old Alpha version that was hosing me.