# Your app couldn't be released because the following APKs use sensitive permissions that haven't been declared : 56

Tags: android, google-play-console

**Error
Your app couldn't be released because the following APKs use sensitive permissions that haven't been declared : 56. If you're attempting a staged roll-out, do a full roll-out instead.**

I am not able to move the update apk from Alpha version to production due to above error. I removed all the sensitive permissions in the previous versions itself.What is the meaning of "sensitive permissions that haven't been declared : 56".

I tried doing full roll-out also but still not allowed to release the updated version.

Comment: when had you uploaded apk over alpha channel? It must be long time back

Comment: what permissions are you now asking for? post a list of those so people can help

Comment: If you for example are asking for the geo location you also have to declare this in the content rating form in the Google Play console

Comment: @PareshMayani I have uploaded APK to Alpha yesterday

Comment: @Kushan No new permissions i am asking and I kept to remove these permission in the manifest if they are using in merged manifest.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373255/google-play-console-preventing-uploading-or-promoting-new-app-versions-compliant/54406150) solved the issue. We have to RETAIN the previous version which we presented the inline permission declaration form. Hope it will help someone to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What 3rd party libraries are you using? My guess is, at least one of them asks for permissions you did not declare in your manifest. Also, if you are using flavours, make sure to check the **auto-generated, merged** manifest. Hope that helps!