# Permission Declaration form for Google playstore for sensitive permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Can you please guide how to raise a Permission Declaration form for a default phone Handler application.  This is the reply which i received from google::

> *Unable to verify core functionality of app
> When you submitted your app, you specified your app's core functionality as follows: **Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Write and Show Call History in Dialer**. However, we couldn’t find evidence that the app offers the declared core functionality during our review. Please submit an updated Permissions Declaration Form that includes instructions on how to verify your declared functionality, and include details such as test account information. If portions of your app are restricted, please share a link to a video of your app to help us verify the core functionalities you’ve declared.*

Am i selecting the right category for default phone handler.
Permissions added are as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Any video link or documentation can help other than google documentation.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689451/permissions-declaration-form-still-showing-in-google-play-console-even-with-upda