# I´m getting the following error from Play Console and I can´t edit the version or the Google play info

Tags: android, google-play

> You will not be able to edit this application until you create a
>   different version in which you declare sensitive permissions

Recently when I trying to update an application I got this error, but either let me upload anything to remedy it, or change the Play store info. I've been searching everywhere and I even contacted Google but they have not answered me yet.

The app is called Enviaje and manage travelers.

The following messages are show when I try to edit the version

[image]

[image]

Sorry if it is in spanish, I`m from Mexico,

And these are the permissions in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I think that the error is caused by the SMS permissions that I had before but that I had to eliminate them by the new Google Play policies

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

I tried to contact Google´s supporst but I they haven´t answered yet.

Comment: You have to increase the version code in your gradle, rebuild the apk and retry the upload

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi we did it . I did not work! We are looking forward to find another solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved it, what you must do first is to create a new version but instead of uploading a new apk or app bundle, you must load one of the library that has SMS or call permissions.

[image: Version library google play]

Then below you will see the form of declaration of services, you fill it according to your situation, and you go to review the version. How is a previous version will not allow you to launch.

You will notice that the warning has disappeared and now you can upload a new version, I recommend that you no longer have the SMS permissions and have made the relevant changes. You have until March 9 to remove them if it is not so Google Play can delete your Play Store application just like that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me

Comment: Thanks :) you save my life

Comment: Thanks man. This is really bizarre!

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I was struggling from last 2 days

Comment: you are great ,saved my day

Comment: There is another working answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361014/google-play-console-said-you-cant-edit-this-app-until-you-create-a-new-app-rel/54686091#54686091

Comment: thank you, saved my day. this should be fixed by google. SMH

Answer (score 0):

Check if my answer here [Error updating app on Google play store after introducing new google policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366163/error-updating-app-on-google-play-store-after-introducing-new-google-policy/54398934?noredirect=1#comment95610612_54398934) can apply to your problem. It's about uploading the build as Beta and then promoting