# "release declaring sensitive permissions" error when added new version that doesn't have sensitive permissions

Tags: android, google-play, store, google-play-console

Im getting this error  when Im adding apk to alpha and beta in play store.
Production is normal.

I found this answers.

[Google play console said "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions" how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361014/google-play-console-said-you-cant-edit-this-app-until-you-create-a-new-app-rel)

[Warnings Your Apk Is Using Permissions That Require A Privacy Policy: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234205/warnings-your-apk-is-using-permissions-that-require-a-privacy-policy-android-p)

Neither Im using read_phone_state permission nor sms,call log permissions

I have attached screen shot my google play store account below.

[image]

I cant see where the real problem is. This page says only just there is an error.

Thats my all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: which permissions you use then? Probably one of the libraries you use is using those permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google play console said "You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions" how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361014/google-play-console-said-you-cant-edit-this-app-until-you-create-a-new-app-rel)

Comment: Check my answer, I had the same problem and I solved it by accident https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371314/i%C2%B4m-getting-the-following-error-from-play-console-and-i-can%C2%B4t-edit-the-version-o/54390732#54390732

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In our case, we **were thinking that we did not have** "Read SMS/Call log" permissions in our app yet, and had the same error. But we were planning to include such features into our app, so **we sumbitted the sensitive permissions declaration form** previously via Google Forms link (before it was integrated into Play Console) and got a decline.

So our solution was:
1. Add `READ_SMS` permission to our apk and increase version code
2. Publish new apk in alpha channel and declare that the release did not comply with the new regulations (in the permission declaration form). After this the error went away.
3. Publish updated APK with this permission removed (which was our goal in the first place)

After step 2 the error went away, so we were able to release our planned apk to production.

**Update:**
It turned out we had an old apk with "Read SMS" permission in our alpha channel. So you can use these instructions to trigger declaration form, but you will still need to delete this apk later in order to comply new rules. This is what we did, after that error went away.

Comment: I completed the Google Form only for READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS Sensible Runtime Permission. Should I complete for the rest of them?
*
*
CAMERA,
    READ_CONTACTS,
   READ_PHONE_STATE,
    GET_ACCOUNTS, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: @Cristofer well, I think this form is related to "Read SMS/Call log" permissions.

Comment: In my case none solution worked, too but then I found this. So I added old permission, put apk to Beta channel, filled in form, didn't even publish it to this channel but create new production version with newer version and removed forbidden permission. The error didn't show and I could release it.

Comment: I do not see where to declare that the release did not comply with the new regulations, I only see main functions, instructions to check the app, instructions to access the app, declarations

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by following these steps,

1. Create a release and instead of uploading new apk/bundle select anyone from the library which has SMS or call permissions.
2. Fill up all the necessary details and the declaration form, save and review.
3. Now go to release management and edit this release and upload the new apk/bundle which you were supposed to upload.
4. Now you wont see any error messages.
5. Fill in all the details, save,review and rollout.

Comment: you mean we have to upload that buggy apk first with permission deceleration first , after that again upload exact apk form the library which has not that sensitive permission.

Comment: @Radhey Yes, You have to upload the apk from library and remove it once review is done and upload the new one

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an alpha or beta release? Check If those releases have sensitive permissions, then release to production.

Comment: I also had an old version of the app in the test release, so it kept asking for permissions, even though I had removed them, when I upgraded the test release apk, I got around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We were seeing this error even though our current release doesn't use these permissions because we had released an old version that did to an internal test track. We deactivated all previous APKs and the error was resolved.

Comment: Can you please guide that how can I deactivate my old release, I changed some options, create new release and in app content->permission declaration form->view app bundles & APKs, there is only old version active shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the permissions which are necessary that application ask during run time, according to the android policy you have to declare them before uploading the APK, in your case you took that permission i.e camera, record audio. [Here](https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/11552-privacy-policy-for-android-apps) you can get more help.

Answer (score 0):

As to [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en) all apps that not meet the new policy and not remove or grant this permissions with google via declaration : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/closedform  may be removed from google play store and not be able to update currently existing one.
From your manifest permissions list you can see you asking for sms and phone related permissions : `READ_CONTACTS, CALL_PHONE`

Comment: Google Forms link is no longer supported. This is a part of Play Console now.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following instructions to submit the declaration form:

A1. Go to the Console > App release > Click ‘Create a release’ > Upload a new APK that you want to release

A2. Retain the current version of APK

A3. Click ‘Add from library’ > Upload all active APKs to cover all permissions across the tracks in your app

You can find active APK in Release management > Artifact library

A4. Fill out the Permissions Declaration Form for extension

‘Compliance status’ > check “No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call log”

‘Declarations’ > check all

A5. Click "Save" at the bottom of the page

After that, please stay on the same page and follow the next steps:

B1. Deactivate and remove ONLY the old APKs which you do not want to release.

B2. Click "Save" again then select "Review"

B3. Then, you'll be able to release a new version of APK by clicking "Start Roll Out" button.

After finished all the steps, if your APK does NOT have sensitive or high-risk permissions anymore, please skip the steps below(C1~4) and no additional action is required. However, if you uploaded the new APK with sensitive or high-risk permissions, please note that your app will be removed after Mar 9, 2019.

If your new APK has sensitive or high-risk permissions & you want to utilize the permission after Mar 9, you need to finish the additional step to submit the declaration form to enable further review.

C1. After the new APK release(Step B1~3), please go to the Console > App release > Click ‘Create a release’

C2. Click ‘Add from library’ > Select the APK(which will be utilized after Mar.9)

C3. Retain newly updated APK in step B3

C4. Fill out Permissions Declaration Form (not for extension),

‘Compliance status’ > check “Yes, this release meets the SMS and Call log”

Choose core functionalities as well

C5. Submit the form by Clicking “Save” at the bottom of the page

Also, to make sure your app be safe after Mar 9, please do not forget to update all the APKs(with sensitive or high-risk permission) in other track with the same steps.